# Is it possible to override drupal_build_css_cache?

Tags: php, drupal, overriding

Since it's bad practice to modify [`drupal_build_css_cache`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_build_css_cache/5) directly ,

does drupal allow overriding this function somehow?

Comment: you asked 18 questions, but accepted only 2 answers as correct. you should really accept some more if you want people to keep answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, it is not: [there is only one call to `drupal_build_css_cache()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_build_css_cache) from other Drupal code, and there is nothing "dynamic" there to make that call overrideable.

why do you want to modify `drupal_build_css_cache()`? what are you trying to achieve? if it is something others might find useful, you might [suggest your idea to the Drupal project and try getting it included into core](http://drupal.org/contribute).

Comment: Yeah, you can do pretty much anything to the CSS itself before it gets cached without touching that function. And if you really want to change how caching itself works, you need to replace more than that function.